# Update Navigation bar

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, uinavigationbar, uipageviewcontroller

All i m trying to do is to update navigation bar when user turns page over. Below is my code

```
- (UIViewController *)pageViewController:(UIPageViewController *)pageViewController 
  viewControllerBeforeViewController:(UIViewController *)viewController {

contentViewController = [[ContentViewController alloc] initWithPDF:PDFDocument];

currentIndex = [modelArray indexOfObject:[(ContentViewController *)viewController page]];

if (currentIndex == 0) {

    return nil; 
}

contentViewController.page = [modelArray objectAtIndex:currentIndex - 1];

 [self updateNavigationBar];

return contentViewController;

}

- (UIViewController *)pageViewController:(UIPageViewController *)pageViewController
   viewControllerAfterViewController:(UIViewController *)viewController {

contentViewController = [[ContentViewController alloc] initWithPDF:PDFDocument];

//get the current page
currentIndex = [modelArray indexOfObject:[(ContentViewController *)viewController page]];

if (currentIndex == totalPages - 1) {

    return nil;
}

contentViewController.page = [modelArray objectAtIndex:currentIndex + 1];

 [self updateNavigationBar];

return contentViewController;

}

-(void) updateNavigationBar{

if (CGPDFDocumentGetNumberOfPages(PDFDocument) > 1) {
    title = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"Page %u of %u", currentIndex - 1, CGPDFDocumentGetNumberOfPages(PDFDocument)];
} else if ((CGPDFDocumentGetNumberOfPages(PDFDocument) < 1) {


 title = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"Page %u of %u", currentIndex + 1, CGPDFDocumentGetNumberOfPages(PDFDocument)];

}
```

But seems like it is not working at all i m able to turn page over but not able to update navigation bar.

and this is the code for navigation bar

```
_navBar = [[UINavigationBar alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, self.view.bounds.size.width, 45)];

_navBar.tintColor = [UIColor colorWithRed:243.0/255.0 green:164.0/255.0 blue:0.0/255.0 alpha:1.0];

title = [[UINavigationItem alloc] initWithTitle:[NSString stringWithFormat:
                                                                   @"Page %u of %u",
                                                                   currentIndex,
                                                                  CGPDFDocumentGetNumberOfPages(PDFDocument)]];
 [_navBar pushNavigationItem:title animated:NO];
```

Please help.

Appreciate it.

Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

updating the navigation bar is done by updating the navigation items:

```
 _navBar.topItem.title = @"Custom title";
[_navBar pushNavigationItem:_navBar.topItem animated:NO];
```

Comment: when i turn page over it converts title into backbutton item and updates title on the backbutton item.

Comment: when i click on the backbuttonitem i can see title sliding and finally showing as backbutton item

Comment: On the view controller you want to update navigation bar title (in `viewDidLoad` method), just change the title of the `navigationItem` of the current view controller: `self.navigationItem.title = @"Custom Title";`